# Printing JSON values

Tags: java, json, file-io

Here's just a chunk of JSON code that I need to access...

```
"forecast":{
        "txt_forecast": {
        "date":"8:00 AM MST",
        "forecastday": [
        {
        "period":0,
        "icon":"partlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
        "title":"Thursday",
        "fcttext":"Partly cloudy. High of 63F. Winds less than 5 mph.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Partly cloudy. High of 17C. Winds less than 5 km/h.",
        "pop":"0"
        }
```

Im having trouble printing nested JSON values. If I wanted to print the "fcttext", how would I go upon doing that? I've tried this...

```
public static void display() {
         JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
         try {
             Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\ABC.json"));

         JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
             String a = (String) jsonObject.get("forecast").toString();
             System.out.println(a);
     } 
         catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } 
         catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } 
         catch (ParseException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
     }
     }
```

What am I doing wrong? [Full JSON code](http://api.wunderground.com/api/54f05b23fd8fd4b0/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/US/CO/Denver.json).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your json is not proper, use jsonlint[1] to check if your json is properly formatted.

Reformatting your JSON to following,

```
{
    "forecast": {
        "txt_forecast": {
            "date": "8: 00AMMST",
            "forecastday": [
                {
                    "period": 0,
                    "icon": "partlycloudy",
                    "icon_url": "http: //icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
                    "title": "Thursday",
                    "fcttext": "Partlycloudy.Highof63F.Windslessthan5mph.",
                    "fcttext_metric": "Partlycloudy.Highof17C.Windslessthan5km/h.",
                    "pop": "0"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Use following code to parse,

```
package com.aamir.stackoverflow;

import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class JSONParserStackOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String request = "{\n" +
                "    \"forecast\": {\n" +
                "        \"txt_forecast\": {\n" +
                "            \"date\": \"8: 00AMMST\",\n" +
                "            \"forecastday\": [\n" +
                "                {\n" +
                "                    \"period\": 0,\n" +
                "                    \"icon\": \"partlycloudy\",\n" +
                "                    \"icon_url\": \"http: //icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif\",\n" +
                "                    \"title\": \"Thursday\",\n" +
                "                    \"fcttext\": \"Partlycloudy.Highof63F.Windslessthan5mph.\",\n" +
                "                    \"fcttext_metric\": \"Partlycloudy.Highof17C.Windslessthan5km/h.\",\n" +
                "                    \"pop\": \"0\"\n" +
                "                }\n" +
                "            ]\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "}";

        JsonElement weatherJSON = new JsonParser().parse(request);
        JsonObject weatherObj = weatherJSON.getAsJsonObject();
        JsonObject forecastObj = weatherObj.get("forecast").getAsJsonObject();
        JsonObject txt_forecast = forecastObj.get("txt_forecast").getAsJsonObject();

        JsonArray forecastDays = txt_forecast.getAsJsonArray("forecastday");


        for(JsonElement forecastDay : forecastDays) {
            System.out.println(forecastDay.getAsJsonObject().get("fcttext").toString());
        }
    }
}
```

I have used Google's GSON[2] library to parse JSON.

[1] http://jsonlint.com/

[2] https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using the Jackson library. I find it much better than using JSONParser. They have an example similar to your case right here -
http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Examples

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with your input - you have unbalanced bracket pairs, i.e.:

```
"forecastday": [
```

is not being closed. You also need to add curly around brackets your text to make it an object.

Comment: The JSON code I have in my questions is only just a chunk of the real one which is almost 1000 lines.

Comment: this chunk by itself is not a valid JSON. the minimum you should supply is a valid JSON string/chunk.